# The remote desktop screen is always a grey background

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvnc

I used the methods described in [this page](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2-Page-3.html) and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/598272/reliable-virtual-desktop-environment-for-amazon-ec2-ubuntu) to connect to the Amazon EC2 ubuntu instance using remote desktop. But I always got a grey background shown in this image: [image]

The log file in ~/.vnc:

```
21/12/14 04:20:23 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 Using protocol version 3.8
21/12/14 04:20:23 Full-control authentication passed by 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
21/12/14 04 20:23   8 bpp, depth s
21/12/14 04:20:23   true colour: max r 7 g 7 b 3, shift r 0 g 3 b 6
21/12/14 04:20:23 Using tight encoding for client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 9
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -65527
21/12/14 04:20:23 Using compression level 9 for client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 Using image quality level 0 for client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 Enabling cursor position updates for client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131072
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
21/12/14 04:20:23 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131071
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131070
21/12/14 04:20:23 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131069
21/12/14 04:20:38 KbdAddEvent: unknown KeySym 0xff15 - allocating KeyCode 89
```

The contents of .vnc/xstartup is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
#unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
gnome-session &
```

The contents of the log file is:

```
22/12/14 15:33:42 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
22/12/14 15:33:42 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
22/12/14 15:33:42 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
22/12/14 15:33:42 All Rights Reserved.
22/12/14 15:33:42 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
22/12/14 15:33:42 Desktop name 'X' (ip-172-31-21-231:1)
22/12/14 15:33:42 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
22/12/14 15:33:42 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
No VNC extension on display :1
Option "--login" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal; you might want to create a profile with the desired setting, and use the new '--profile' option
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

(gnome-terminal:3848): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

** (process:3849): WARNING **: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1

** (gnome-session:3849): CRITICAL **: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

22/12/14 15:33:53 Got connection from client *.*.5.179
22/12/14 15:33:54 Using protocol version 3.8
22/12/14 15:33:54 Enabling TightVNC protocol extensions
22/12/14 15:33:56 Full-control authentication passed by *.*.5.179
22/12/14 15:33:56 Using tight encoding for client *.*.5.179
22/12/14 15:33:56 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/12/14 15:33:56 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/12/14 15:33:56 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client *.*.5.179
22/12/14 15:33:56 Enabling cursor position updates for client *.*.5.179
22/12/14 15:33:56 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client *.*.5.179
```

From the log file we can see there is an error "CRITICAL **: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....". I wonder if it is the reason for unity's not appearing.

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Follow-up: I followed the steps in [this article](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/using-vnc-to-operate-a-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04), but the screen now becomes the one in this image: tinypic.com/r/2mnm4vm/8 -- there is no unity desktop.

Comment: no problem. Copy-paste of error output would be much nicer than a screenshot though, because that allows search to find your questions and any potential answers.

Comment: @HBruijn: I tried copy&paste of error output, but they are displayed without "\n", I don't know how to format it, so I had to take a screenshot.

Comment: It look very like only X Server launched without any desktop or apps or desktop manager.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you need to edit your xstartup file (found in the .vnc folder). This link should give you a good start on what you need to edit...if it doesn't work, just post what you have, and we'll work from there.

Ok, let's try modifying your xstartup file to match mine, and then, if you have trouble connecting, we'll see about that. This is from a working file (just pulled it from my file server, though it's a Mint box, it should work for you).

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrcxrdb $HOME/.Xresources
#xsetroot -solid grey
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#/etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback &
```

The fallback stuff is in case gnome crashes (kind of important), because it usually does (in my world). TightVNC is what I have installed, as well as xRDP (so I can RDP in from Windows or Linux).

(Screenshots of the fun in action):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbAIu.png

Comment: I tried the steps in the article you gave. The situation becomes complicated. If I connect using Remmina with sever specified as `localhost:1` as does the article, the windows contains only three check boxes saying "Accept clipboard from viewers", "Send clipboard to viewers" and "Send primary selection to viewers", respectively. If I connect using Remmina with sever specified as `localhost:5902` (my 5902 port is occupied by Xvnc4 because I installed one on my local host), the window contains only a terminal with the three check boxes at the background. (more to continue ...)

Comment: ... But there is no unity components on the desktop such as launcher, topbar or wall paper. If I connect directly without tunneling ssh, the screen is the same as `localhost:1` case, no terminal window available. Could you please help me find out why there is no unity desktop?

Comment: Now my .vnc/xstartup file is exactly the same as the one in the article.

Comment: user280121, still having problems?

Comment: Have you tried swapping 'x-window-manager &' with 'gnome-session &' as per the directions?

Comment: @user3799003: Now I can see a terminal window in the desktop in stead of a grey background. But there is only a terminal; the unity does not appear. I have tried to replace 'x-window-manager &' with 'gnome-session &' (and I edited the post accordingly), but the problem is the same -- no unity.

Comment: I also tried to replace `vncserver` with `tightvncserver`, but the same thing results.

Comment: I copied the xstartup in the answer and restart the vncserver. The situation becomes even worse. Originally I can at least see a terminal window, but now the whole screen is a grey background, just as the first figure in my question.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:` should be two separate lines. Can't be written in a single line.

Comment: Hi, Merry Christmas. How about my problem?